# EF Core query produces additional column for navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

This are my entities:

```
[Table("AktAdr")]
public class ActivityAddress 
{
    [Column("AktID")]
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }

    [Column("AktAdr")]
    public string AddressId { get; set; }

    [Column("AktCID")]
    public int LoginUserId { get; set; }

    public LoginUser LoginUser { get; set; }

    [Column("AdrGrp")]
    public int AdrGrpId { get; set; }
}

[Table("CContact")]
public class LoginUser 
{
    [Column("ID")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Column("txt1")]
    public string  PersonelNumber { get; set; }
 }
```

and this is the definition of the relationship:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<ActivityAddress>()
      .HasOne(e => e.LoginUser)
      .WithMany()
      .HasForeignKey(e => e.LoginUserId)
      .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.Id)
      .IsRequired(false);
```

Now, when I execute

```
var act = ctx.ActivityAddresses
             .Include(x => x.LoginUser)
             .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ActivityId == 549841);
```

I get the exception

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'LoginUserId1'

I wonder why the `LoginUserId1` column is in the query. Isn't it defined anywhere?

Can someone help me what I'm doing wrong or where does EF Core get this column from?

Comment: Remove `[NotMapped]` attribute from navigation property.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks, but this doesn't solve the problem. I have removed it in the question yet.

Comment: I have changed the property to int? because it is not required - but still the same problem :-(

Comment: See the answer below. If it still doesn't work, then there is something not shown here (some  "little" detail is missing)

Comment: It doesn't reproduce even with the original code. So you definitely have something like `public ICollection<ActivityAddress> ActivityAddresses { get; set; }` in `LoginUser` class.

Comment: mmhh - when I add the collection, it is working ...

Answer (score 0):

you will have to fix LoginUser. It needs a key, and key can't be nullable, since LoginUserId is not nullable, and EF creates shadow LoginUserId1 property as a key. Make Id not nullable or LoginUserId nullable. And add ActivityAddresses as navigation property too.

```
[Table("CContact")]
public class LoginUser 
{
    [Column("ID")]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("txt1")]
    public string  PersonelNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ActivityAddress> ActivityAddresses {get; set;}
 }
```

and you will have to fix  the fluent APIs to make Id as  a key and include new navigation property

Comment: If a property is named ID or <entity name>ID (not case-sensitive), it will be configured as the primary key.

Comment: @BennoDual Yes, you are right but this property should not be nullable,  since a PK can't be nullable. So EF couldn't use Id as a primary key and created another one